# how can I put condition to get second position element in a column value, which is comma separated in sql

Tags: sql

Example,

Suppose I have following column values as in column1 in three rows,

```
10,9,2,3
12,9,8,9
16,2,9,2
```

I need to get the records based on column1 value with 2nd position value to be 9.

Result I am expecting as follows,

```
10,9,2,3
12,9,8,9
```

Thanks
Rajasekar R

Comment: Don't store data like comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble. (As you may have noticed now.)

Comment: Poor [normalization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/dbms/database_normalization.htm) is the root cause for this problem, and many more future problems. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? ("SQL" is not a DBMS product, it's query language used by all relational DBMS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try Regex**

```
select * from a where a1 ~ '^\d+[,][9][,]';
```

or

```
select * from a where a1 ~ '^\d+,9,';
```

Both work flawlessly

***For Input***

```
ABC
DEF
HIJ
1,9,2,3
5,9,4,6
1,2,3,9
2,3,3,9
5,99,4,6
10,9,2,3
12,9,8,9
16,2,9,2
162,9,2
```

***Output***

```
1,9,2,3
5,9,4,6
10,9,2,3
12,9,8,9
162,9,2
```

I am having Postgres So I used `~` , for others you can use respective regex command

Answer (score 0):

You can try above example (SQL) for your case :

```
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE(Value NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES('10,9,2,3');
INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES('12,9,8,9');
INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES('16,2,9,2');

SELECT * 
FROM @tempTable
WHERE SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX(',', Value)+1,1) = '9'
```

Comment: what if second value contains more than one digit!? i.e. `10,239,2,3` , `12,239,2,3` , etc. it's a good practice I prefer to do it.

Comment: @Farhęg the question is "to be 9", it different "contains 9"

Comment: No, sorry, the _to be 9_  was just for sample data, the question is:  _how can I put condition to get second position element in a column value, which is comma separated in sql?_

Comment: @Farhęg I see :D. The idea is using CHARINDEX, we can change any conditions, I just give example :)